# Предлоги "НА" и "ДЛЯ" одинаковы по значению?

Tags: предлоги

Здравствуйте!У меня такой вопрос - являются ли предлоги "на и "для" одинаковыми по значению?
К примеру.Человек собрался ехать на горнолыжный курорт.Организация,где он работал обязалась возместить все расходы на отдых.
Этот человек купил горнолыжный костюм для отдыха.
В данном случае эти затраты входят в смысловое выражение "на отдых"?
Или в данном случае в смысл этого выражения входят только затраты произведённые во время отдыха?

Answer (score 2):

Основным значением винительный падежа является его направленность на объект, при наличии предлога НА это будет целью объекта: РАСХОДЫ НА ОТДЫХ. Одним из основных значений Р.п. является достигательное значение границ предмета, поэтому мы имеем не цель (отдых), а СОПРИЧАСТНОСТЬ К ЦЕЛИ (к отдыху). Костюм можно взять напрокат – тогда организация должна будет оплатить эти расходы. Если ж человек купил костюм, то после окончания отдыха он у него останется. Следовательно, организация должна оплатить разницу в стоимости покупки и проката.

ОТВЕТ 2. К сожалению, не могу с Вами согласиться. Полагаю, что вы не отрицаете обобщенное значение  падежей? А далее я рассматриваю ситуацию, в которой, вследствие различия значений падежей, бухгалтерия может оспорить необоснованные расходы. Костюм на отдых – такое выражение вообще кажется странным, говорят «для отдыха», для катания на лыжах, отсюда все его фасоны.

Answer (score 2):

> Предлоги "НА" и "ДЛЯ" одинаковы по значению?

Вообще - нет конечно.
В примерах, подобных Ващему, можно усмотреть некоторое сближение, но не полное.
С отдыхом, пример, кстати не очень удачен.
Потому, что тут вообще довольно далекое занчение.
Костюм на отдых - то, что вы планиреут использовать на отдыхе, вроде как запас га этот случай.
Костюм для отдыха - модель, фасон и т.п. самого костюма.

Вот ежели сравнивать "костюм для ближайшего отпуска" и "костюм на ближайший отпуск", то значения будут весьма близкими.

Расходы/затраты тут абсолютно ни при чем. Просто в бухгалтерии принято говорить о расходах НА ПРИОБРЕТЕНИЕ чего-либо. Или просто НА что-либо. В этих значениях ДЛЯ не используется.

Answer (score 1):

Да нет, не являются. Расходы могут быть НА что-то, а вот горнолыжный костюм покупается ДЛЯ чего-то или ДЛЯ кого-то. То есть, для чьего-то пользования.